# Why is $\langle \psi| \sigma_z |\psi \rangle=\cos(\phi_1)\cos(\phi_2)$ for $|\psi\rangle=R_y(\phi_2)R_x(\phi_1)|0\rangle$?

Tags: measurement, textbook-and-exercises, pennylane

I'm trying some [example](https://pennylane.ai/qml/demos/tutorial_qubit_rotation.html) with the rotation gates and stuck here:

$$\langle \psi| \sigma_z |\psi \rangle
= \langle 0 | R_x(\phi_1)^\dagger R_y(\phi_2)^\dagger \sigma_z  R_y(\phi_2) R_x(\phi_1) | 0 \rangle
= \cos(\phi_1)\cos(\phi_2).
$$

How did they get $\cos(\phi_1)\cos(\phi_2)$?

I pleased to know some clear steps to have an intuition about it. Thanks!

Comment: Use Euler's formula: $e^{i\theta \hat{A}} = cos(\theta)I+isin(\theta)\hat{A}$, where $\hat{A}$ is the matrix satisfy $\hat{A}*\hat{A}=I$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I have just solved it your way but it's become complex quickly. Is there any short solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe it is best to just work out the calculation step-by-step.

First, let $U =  R_y(\phi_2) R_x(\phi_1) $, and $|\psi \rangle = U|0\rangle$.

The goal is to calculate $ \langle \psi| \sigma_z |\psi \rangle$ where $\sigma_z = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & -1  \end{pmatrix}$.

1. Computing $|\psi \rangle$ explicitly.

\begin{align}
U|0 \rangle &= R_y(\phi_1)R_x(\phi_2) |0\rangle =\begin{pmatrix}
                \cos{\dfrac{\phi_1}{2}} & -\sin\dfrac{\phi_1}{2} \\
                \sin\dfrac{\phi_1}{2} & \cos\dfrac{\phi_1}{2}
            \end{pmatrix}  \begin{pmatrix}
                \cos\dfrac{\phi_2}{2}   & -i\sin\dfrac{\phi_2}{2} \\
                -i\sin\dfrac{\phi_2}{2} & \cos\dfrac{\phi_2}{2}
            \end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}1 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}\\
&= \begin{pmatrix}
                \cos{\dfrac{\phi_1}{2}} & -\sin\dfrac{\phi_1}{2} \\
                \sin\dfrac{\phi_1}{2} & \cos\dfrac{\phi_1}{2}
            \end{pmatrix} 
\begin{pmatrix}\cos\dfrac{\phi_2}{2} \\ -i\sin\dfrac{\phi_2}{2} \end{pmatrix}\\
&= \begin{pmatrix}
\cos\dfrac{\phi_1}{2}\cos\dfrac{\phi_2}{2} + i\sin\dfrac{\phi_1}{2}\sin\dfrac{\phi_2}{2} \\ 
\sin\dfrac{\phi_1}{2}\cos\dfrac{\phi_2}{2} - i\cos\dfrac{\phi_1}{2}\sin\dfrac{\phi_2}{2}  \end{pmatrix} = |\psi\rangle\\
\end{align}

2. Compute $\sigma_z|\psi\rangle$
   $$\sigma_z|\psi\rangle = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & -1  \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix}
   \cos\dfrac{\phi_1}{2}\cos\dfrac{\phi_2}{2} + i\sin\dfrac{\phi_1}{2}\sin\dfrac{\phi_2}{2} \\ 
   \sin\dfrac{\phi_1}{2}\cos\dfrac{\phi_2}{2} - i\cos\dfrac{\phi_1}{2}\sin\dfrac{\phi_2}{2}  \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}
   \cos\dfrac{\phi_1}{2}\cos\dfrac{\phi_2}{2} + i\sin\dfrac{\phi_1}{2}\sin\dfrac{\phi_2}{2} \\ 
   -\sin\dfrac{\phi_1}{2}\cos\dfrac{\phi_2}{2} + i\cos\dfrac{\phi_1}{2}\sin\dfrac{\phi_2}{2}  \end{pmatrix} = |\phi \rangle $$
3. Compute $ \langle \psi| \sigma_z |\psi \rangle = \langle \psi | \phi \rangle $

\begin{align}
\langle \psi | \phi \rangle &= \begin{pmatrix}
\cos\dfrac{\phi_1}{2}\cos\dfrac{\phi_2}{2} - i\sin\dfrac{\phi_1}{2}\sin\dfrac{\phi_2}{2} &
\sin\dfrac{\phi_1}{2}\cos\dfrac{\phi_2}{2} + i\cos\dfrac{\phi_1}{2}\sin\dfrac{\phi_2}{2}  \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix}
\cos\dfrac{\phi_1}{2}\cos\dfrac{\phi_2}{2} + i\sin\dfrac{\phi_1}{2}\sin\dfrac{\phi_2}{2} \\ 
-\sin\dfrac{\phi_1}{2}\cos\dfrac{\phi_2}{2} + i\cos\dfrac{\phi_1}{2}\sin\dfrac{\phi_2}{2}  \end{pmatrix} \\
&= \cos^2\dfrac{\phi_1}{2}\cos^2\dfrac{\phi_2}{2} + \sin^2\dfrac{\phi_1}{2}\sin^2\dfrac{\phi_2}{2}  - \sin^2\dfrac{\phi_1}{2}\cos^2\dfrac{\phi_2}{2} - \cos^2\dfrac{\phi_1}{2}\sin^2\dfrac{\phi_2}{2} \\
&= \cos(\phi_1)\cos(\phi_2) \hspace{1 cm} \textrm{(Trig identities manipulation)}
\end{align}

Comment: If I follow this way, I can reduce the number of calculations as below:
$\langle 0|M|0\rangle = a$ with a is the top-left element of $2x2$ $M$ matrix. So we can just focus on it.